# Triple volume integral of divergence

Tags: integration, vector-fields, divergence-theorem

S is given by $z = \sqrt{x^2+ y^2} \ $ for $1 ≤ z ≤ 4$, then calculate $\nabla \cdot \vec{F} \ $ for the vector field $\vec{F} = (xz, −zy, x^3)$.

Evaluate $I = \iiint \ (\nabla \cdot \vec{F}) \ dV$ ,
where $V$ is the volume enclosed by the surface S and the two discs
{(x, y, z) : x^2+y^2 ≤ 1 , z = 2} and {(x, y, z) : x^2+y^2 ≤ 9 , z = 3}$.

I got a negative answer it thet right?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Where are you getting stuck? Also please use $$ for all of the math objects.

Comment: Please check my edit and see if everything is as given in the question. Also as Countable mentioned, it is not that hard to use basic mathjax. Put your mathematical expressions within \$ \$. And use \ before sqrt etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason why the surface integral cannot be negative. Also the divergence of a vector field can be negative or negative in certain regions and positive in others.

As far as your integral, you have not completely written it so difficult to say where you went wrong but if the first limit mentioned is of $r$, it is not correct.

In your case, $\vec{F} = (z, -zy, x^2)$

The surface is cone $z = \sqrt{x^2+y^2} \ $ along with two discs $x^2+y^2 \leq 1$ at $z = 1$ and $x^2+y^2 \leq 9$ at $z = 3$. So we have a closed surface and applying divergence theorem,

$div{\vec{F}} = \nabla \cdot \vec{F} = -z$ as you mentioned. So your integral is,

$\displaystyle \int_0^{2\pi} \int_1^3 \int_0^z \ (-z) \ r \ dr \ dz \ d\theta = -20 \pi$

Comment: If you take $r$ and $z$ independent of each other, that will give you volume of the cylinder (annulus) between radius $1$ and $3$ and of height $2 = 3 - 1$. In case of cone $z = \sqrt{x^2+y^2} = r$ so $r$ and $z$ are not independent. Take any disc at height $z$ on the cone. You get a disc with radius $z$. To find the area of this disc ($\pi z^2$) you integrate between $0$ and $z$.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing forbids you from having a negative flux because it’s just an integral.

Through that surface you have portions where the field is outgoing, hence it has the same direction of the external local normal versor of the surface, and other portions where the field is incoming, hence it has the opposite direction of the external local normal versor.

The net balance is the value measured by the integral.

You are always calculating the flux as a outgoing flux, so if it’s positive it means that it’s mainly outgoing, while if it’s negative then it is mainly incoming.